# lodash/underscore find the number of non-unique elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array with some number of strings and I need to find out how many of the strings are not unique - the opposite of _.uniq.  I've tried a few things but have come up with dead ends so far.  I get the feeling the answer is simple.  Take for example:

```
["abc", "abc", "def", "rty", "rty", "rty", "uig", "ghe", "bed", "abc"]
```

I'd like to get an answer of 2 from this because only two of the strings are in the array more than once.

Comment: Well, this is fairly easy to do without any library, but do you need it using `lodash`/`underscore`?

Comment: @MinusFour, I prefer it with lodash/underscore because I think in terms of lodash/underscore more so than vanilla JS.  I'll take it however it is easiest for you to provide it though and try and figure out any details from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are looking for a cheap and cross browser solution to your problem?; by using underscore or lodash, designed for ES3+. But, you must be careful with the strings that you have in your list.

Let's take a look at MinusFour's answer.

```js
var $countOfLikeStrings3 = function(arrayOfStrings) {
  var repeated = {
    length: 0
  };

  _.reduce(arrayOfStrings, function(acc, val) {
    if (acc[val] !== undefined) {
      if (repeated[val] === undefined) {
        repeated[val] = true;
        repeated.length++;
      }
    }

    acc[val] = true;

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return repeated.length;
}

var pre = document.getElementById('out');

function log(result) {
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result + '\n'));
}

var list1 = ['length', 'length', 'constructor', 'constructor', 'prototype', 'prototype', '__proto__', '__proto__'];

log($countOfLikeStrings3(list1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

I guess we didn't expect a result of 1?

An now aquinas solution.

```js
var $countOfLikeStrings2 = function(arrayOfStrings) {
  return _.filter(_.groupBy(arrayOfStrings), function(n) {
    return n.length > 1;
  }).length;
}

var pre = document.getElementById('out');

function log(result) {
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result + '\n'));
}

var list1 = ['length', 'length', 'constructor', 'constructor', 'prototype', 'prototype', '__proto__', '__proto__'];

log($countOfLikeStrings2(list1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Again, weren't expecting 3?

Ok, so now let's use some modern ES6, so browser support is reduced but this will work on current mainstream browsers and node.

```js
var $countOfLikeStrings1 = (function(create) {
  'use strict';

  var symRepeated = Symbol('repeated'),
    symLength = Symbol('length');

  return function(arrayOfStrings) {
    var accumulator = create(null);

    accumulator[symRepeated] = create(null);
    accumulator[symRepeated][symLength] = 0;

    return arrayOfStrings.reduce(function(acc, stringItem) {
      var repeated = acc[symRepeated],
        count = (acc[stringItem] || 0) + 1;

      acc[stringItem] = count;
      if (count > 1) {
        if (!repeated[stringItem]) {
          repeated[symLength] += 1;
        }

        repeated[stringItem] = count;
      }

      return acc;
    }, accumulator)[symRepeated][symLength];
  };
}(Object.create));

var pre = document.getElementById('out');

function log(result) {
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result + '\n'));
}

var list1 = ['length', 'length', 'constructor', 'constructor', 'prototype', 'prototype', '__proto__', '__proto__'];

log($countOfLikeStrings1(list1));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Hey! That's more like it, 4!

So, there may even be better ways in ES6 - I'm still learning the new stuff. And with a little additional ES3 and ES5 code, the other two solutions could also be improved.

Those problems aside, here is a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/32423512) of these 3 solutions as they stand.

Update: reworked to be even more ES6

```js
function $countOfLikeStrings4(arrayOfStrings) {
  'use strict';

  const accumulator = new Map(),
    repeated = new Map();

  var oldCount,
    newCount;

  for (let stringItem of arrayOfStrings) {
    oldCount = accumulator.get(stringItem) || 0;
    newCount = oldCount + 1;
    accumulator.set(stringItem, newCount);
    if (newCount > 1 && !repeated.has(stringItem)) {
      repeated.set(stringItem, true);
    }
  }

  return repeated.size;
}

var pre = document.getElementById('out');

function log(result) {
  pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result + '\n'));
}

var list1 = ['length', 'length', 'constructor', 'constructor', 'prototype', 'prototype', '__proto__', '__proto__'];

log($countOfLikeStrings4(list1));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: I just realize the mistake I made. I always though literals were created like `Object.create(null)` as in pure objects not being an instance of any prototype, but i guess that's not the case.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like __proto__, no doubt because that property is not configurable by default. Interesting. That actually feels like a bug in lodash...

Comment: lodash is a very good library, but continues to be written in ES3 for compatibility and so it is going to suffer some some edge cases like this. But it probably could be fixed in lodash doing something like `{}.__proto__ = null;` but I've not done any research into this and don't know what side effects or performance implications it would have on the library.

Answer (score 5):

```
var list = ["abc", "abc", "def", "rty", "rty", "rty", "uig", "ghe", "bed", "abc"];

var repeatedCount = _.filter(_.groupBy(list), function(n) { return n.length > 1; }).length;
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this solution! Damn I even used it recently. Thanks a mil. I understand this one well. MinusFour's solution is just as good though and he beat you to it - +1 for you.

Comment: Well, actually MinusFour's solution *isn't* just as good :). His solution is O(n^2) and my solution is O(N). For small arrays it probably won't matter. For larger arrays it absolutely will. See this comparison: https://jsfiddle.net/x5pjdugd/ 

His solution takes > 5 *seconds*, mine takes 95ms. IE 11 doesn't even seem to finish. If you go to this version in IE 11 https://jsfiddle.net/x5pjdugd/1 which uses a smaller array, his version takes 26 seconds, mine took ~400ms.

Comment: You could replace the call to _.groupBy with _.countBy and the filter function then reduces to `return n > 1`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it with `underscore`. You just keep searching on the accumulator for repeated values and adding non-unique items to another object/array. Note: This works only for an array of strings.

```js
var list = ["eyxCyqqbn3", "jPEbM00mvQ", "5pi7wTh689", "P2iBGGwuWZ", "eyxCyqqbn3", "jPEbM00mvQ", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "yXkmkZo0lW", "5pi7wTh689", "P2iBGGwuWZ", "uX1GrD4UQt", '__proto__', '__proto__'];
var repeated = Object.create(null);
_.reduce(list, function(acc, val) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(acc, val)) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(repeated, val)) {
      repeated[val] = true;
    }
  }
  acc[val] = true;
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

var amountrepeated = Object.keys(repeated).length;

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = amountrepeated;
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: Your code snippet works here as illustrated and in my environment but in further testing with longer arrays it does not work.  Try this one for example as list: ["eyxCyqqbn3", "jPEbM00mvQ", "5pi7wTh689", "P2iBGGwuWZ", "eyxCyqqbn3", "jPEbM00mvQ", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "uX1GrD4UQt", "yXkmkZo0lW", "5pi7wTh689", "P2iBGGwuWZ", "uX1GrD4UQt"] ;

Comment: I made a mistake with the returned value, it's fixed now.

Comment: @aquinas, you are right. It's mostly because of the indexOf calls... which are bad. I got around that now.

Comment: Now you should use "hasOwnProperty", otherwise if the strings in the list contain "length" or "valueOf" etc. they wouldn't show up as being a duplicate. Example: replace your list with: 

`var list = ["length", "length", "valueOf", "valueOf"];` it will say 0 items were repeated.

Comment: Another edge case now would be if you had a sparse array like `[ , undefined]` or `[ , , 1]`. These would not count he undefined or holes. But like I said, this is edge case and of no concern if you have a dense array of actual strings. Thought I'd just mention it. ;)

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't work for an array of other types as it tries to get a string of the key index. Some values might be counted as duplicated as their string representation might just match some other previous value.